# Read object inside bundle on gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to receive a google cloud message. I followed the official guideline and the message was received but on a weird format somehow.

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    String title = data.getString("title");

    createNotification(title, message);
}}
```

the "message" is OK, bit "title" is null. so using a break point, I found that the data is in this format:

> Bundle[{google.sent_time=1470675575536, to=/notifications, data=**{"alert_cat_id":"urgent","title":"your title","message":"your message"}**, google.message_id=0:1470675575544420%a19a831ef9fd7ecd, ***message=your message***, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

what I need is the object "data" inside the bundle, but why I can get only "message"?

Comment: How are you sending your push notification? If you send it programmatically, please post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your push data is a bit strange but here how you can implement this.

First include gson to your project:

```
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '1.7.2'
```

Second create a class like below:

```
public class Notification{
   @SerializedName("alert_cat_id")
   private String alertCatId;
   @SerializedName("title")
   private String title;
   @SerializedName("message")
   private String message;

   // Generate getters and setters.
}
```

When you receive push convert the data and get title and message from it.

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    //String message = data.getString("message");
    //String title = data.getString("title");
    String notificationData = title = data.getString("data");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Notification n = gson.fromJson(notificationData, Notification.class);
    createNotification(n.getTitle(), n.getMessage());
}}
```